# PHP аналог array_unique без ключей

Tags: php

Имеется ли аналог этой команды, чтобы определялись уникальные слова, без указания ключа первого вхождения? Может у этой команды есть какой-нибудь параметр, отвечающий за это?
Результат:

```
    color":{
        "0":"Черный",
        "1":"Белый",
        "2":"Серый"
}
```

Необходимо:

```
color":{"Черный","Белый","Серый"}
```

Comment: При чем тут `array_unique`?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan не совсем понял вас.Я применил эту команду к array, результат показан в 1 коде. Мне нужно сделать как во 2. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Ключи будут в любом случае, это же массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php) — убирает повторяющиеся значения из массива. Примените к полученной последовательности метод [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php) - он выберет все значения массива (ключи будут отброшены). К примеру:

```
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input); // Array([a] => green, [0] => red, [1] => blue)
print_r(array_values($result)); // Array([0] => green, [1] => red, [2] => blue)
```